# What happens if we write a remote anonymous proxy in local proxy address?

Tags: proxy

I can not connect to Tor network with bridges. I set a remote anonymous proxy (as if it is a local proxy) and then tor could connect to the network. I wonder if Tor connects to the first node through this proxy and the connection between Tor browser and the proxy is encrypted.

Comment: Where did you set the proxy settings?

Comment: Tor Network Settings...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Tor connects to the first node over the proxy. The proxy connection isn't encrypted, but the data sent over it will be.

Note that if a simple proxy works, it's likely that other bridges will work too, it's possible that only the default bridges don't work.

A proxy should only be used in situations where it's required to access external internet resources (common on corporate networks) and potentially against poorly configured censorship systems. Note that single hop proxies are *not* "anonymous" for any meaningful value of "anonymous".

Comment: You mean Tor encrypts data before connecting to the proxy, but ISP or another one can still see that my computer is connecting to the proxy?

Comment: Yes, and it can see you're connecting to Tor.